# Automatically insert some data before input text

Tags: laravel

Hi I wanted to send some text before input text for identify which category is it. I'm using Laravel 9.

CONDITION (For example)

```
Input Field
<input type="text" name="topic" id="topic">
```

When the user input `Math` in the text field then the "Book" keyword should be automatically inserted into the database

final output should be = `Math Book`

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if (!empty($request->source)) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count((array)$request->source); $i++) {

                $post = new bajet;
                $post->date = $request->date[$i];
                $post->ab = $request->ab[$i];
                $post->source = $request->source[$i];
                $post->kriyakalap = $request->kriyakalap[$i];
                $post->sub_topic = $request->sub_topic[$i];
                $post->summary = $request->summary.'book';
                $post->cash = $request->cash[$i];
                $post->save();
            }
        }
        return redirect(route('index'))->with('status', 'बजेट समाबेश भयो !!');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could prefixed text as:

```
//this is your input text 
$topic = $request->input('topic');

$topicForDatabase = 'Book '.$topic;
```

In this way you could concatenate the text in PHP, now you need to store this `$topicForDatabase` in the database. Here, is the [sandbox](https://onlinephp.io/c/ec987).